# Tab bar controller didn't show right bar button item: Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I can't add the button to the tableView screen after the TabBarController screen and move a segue to the next screen. And I can't add a title to this screen. I'm adding a button, and can't see it, the same thing with a title.

My storyboard looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find a solve for this problem, i'm deleted first navigation controller and switch a presentation for tab bar controller as full screen, and after them add navigation controller